# MongoDB error while hosting web app on Cyclic.sh?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-deployment

When I hosted my web-app on cyclic.sh "npm run start" script is returning an error in deployment logs.
App is working fine when i am running it on my localhost.

```
2022-12-09 23:24:41.993: MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"
    at new ConnectionString (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:86:19)
    at parseOptions (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js:200:17)
    at new MongoClient (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:45:63)
    at /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:801:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.openUri (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:798:19)
    at /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:412:10
    at /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
2022-12-09 23:24:42.011: 

ERROR: Failed to run "npm run start". Start script defined in package.json:

            "scripts": {
                "start":  "node server.js"
                 ...
            
Exited with code: 1
```

Here is code:
file: db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}
module.exports= connectDB;
```

file: server.js

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT ||4000;
connectDB().then(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log("listening for requests");
  })
})
```

I tried including useNewUrlParser but it didn't work.

Comment: Is process.env.MONGO_URI value correct?

Comment: Yes, and it is working fine when I am running with my localhost
 MONGO_URI = "mongodb+srv://manavs2110:manavs@cluster0.k6kjx30.mongodb.net/grip?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the environment variables in the app dashboard? If you did, be sure to remove the quotes if you have them